# Trigger to Roll-up on lookup relationship

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a lookup relationship between Contract(Parent) and Expenses__c
want to summarize the value of the field called Amout in Expenses__c to a custom field in Contract called Tot_instalment__c.

Please help me to find where the errors are in the code. Attached is the list of the problem.

```
trigger UpdateTotInstalment on Expenses__c (after insert, after delete, after undelete, after update) {
    set<id> ids=new set<id>();
    for(Expenses__c exp: trigger.new)
        ids.add(exp.ContractNumber__c);
    List<contract> contractToUpdate=new List<Contract>();
    Map<ID, contract> cont = new Map<ID, contract>([select id ,Tot_Instalment__c from Contract where id:=ids]);
    AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT ContractNumber__c,SUM(Amount__c)amt FROM Expenses__c where ContractNumber__c in:ids group by ContractNumber__c];

    for(AggregateResult Results: groupedResults){
         Id ContractNumber__c =(id) Results.get('ContractNumber__c');         
         Contract c = cont.get(ContractNumber__c);
         c.Tot_Instalment__c=(integer)Results.get('amt');
         contractToUpdate.add(c);
    }    
  update contractToUpdate;
}
```

[image: List of error]

Comment: You could use Andrew Fawcett's [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) instead of trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

The errors give you a good hint at what's wrong here.

Let's look at line 6, with some line breaks to make things easy to see

```
Map<ID, contract> cont = new Map<ID, contract>(
    [select id, Tot_Instalment__c 
    from Contract 
    where id := ids]
);
```

We have 2 equals signs here.

`cont = new map...`
`where id := ids`

The first one is fine, and the second one is where your error lies.

Binding apex variables in a SOQL query uses `: <variable>` syntax.

You need to change `where id := ids` to `where id = :ids` or `where id IN :ids`
Notice the order of the colon and equals sign.

Comment: Thanks!!!  Now, i have only on problem in the line 10.  The error message is : Invalid Caracter in identifier "ContractNumber__c"

Comment: @GirbsonBIJOU Try to figure this one out on your own. It's a straightforward error and should be easy to resolve with a little bit of effort.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is i do not have strong code skills. But i will try. Thank you

Comment: @GirbsonBIJOU All the more reason to use the DLRS tool then. Alternatively, struggling with and overcoming errors is a way to become a better programmer. When you run into an error (or a bunch of errors), start looking at the lowest line number (one syntax error can cascade into more errors). Take the time to _read_ and _digest_ the error message(s). Try to work out what might be a problem and, just as importantly, what _can't_ be a problem. This is the process I used to arrive at my answer.

Comment: Problem solved:  I used the name of the field ContractNumber__c instead of  any variable name.